# Pip inside virtualenv install packages in the wrong place

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

So I tried to install `flask` package inside `virtualenv`.

```
$ virtualenv env
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/egor/Documents/python/projects/flask/env/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/egor/Documents/python/projects/flask/env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
$ . ./env/bin/activate
(env) $ sudo pip3 install flask
```

After this I tried to import `flask` package in python and got `ImportError` exception. `(env) $ pip3 freeze` gave me nothing.
Then I've discovered package in `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages` directory.

So basically `pip3` inside `vurtualenv` install packages in the wrong place.
How can I solve this problem? Is it because of `Using base prefix '/usr'` line?

Comment: can you give us the results of the following command (from within the virtualenv) ```which pip3```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `pip` doesn't need root privilege (especially in a virtual env). Try `pip3 install flask` without `sudo`.